# ghostscript cygwin

Tags: unix, cygwin

I am using cygwin (unix) for windows and would like to install ghostscript so I can run a convert for ImageMagick to go from PDF to tif. However, in order to do this, I need ghostscript. I have looked at different websites to install it on cygywin but I do not understand. Here is the site I have tried to use [here](http://ghostscript.com/doc/7.07/Install.htm)

Can anyone please explain to me how this is done? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to install GhostScript (gs) through the Cygwin setup.exe program.  See http://cygwin.com/install.html for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I am new to this but isn't setup.exe when you are installing cygwin from scratch? I have already installed cygwin. Thanks for your help

Comment: and setup.exe tells me setup.exe command not found

Comment: You can re-run setup.exe to add/remove/update packages in your existing Cygwin install.

Comment: When I reinstalled it, I chose the all option but nothing. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @michael, check this out http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/setup.html